# Сохранение значения Spinner в SharedPreferences и далее его подстановка

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

Хочу реализовать сохранение значения `Spinner` и последующую подстановку его в тот же `Spinner`. То есть при входе в настройки приложения будет установлена тема, которая сохранена в спиннере (исходя из значения в `SharedPreferences`). А потом можно будет выбирать значение из `Spinner`, затем оно опять сохраняется в `SharedPreferences`.

```
package com.churkin.oneapp;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner spinnercolor;
    SharedPreferences colorPref;
    final String COLOR_PREF = "COLOR_PREF";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        setTitle("Настройки");
        spinnercolor = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnercolor);
        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinnersettings, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnercolor.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinLoad();
        spinnercolor.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String[] choose = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinnersettings);
                String item = (String)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                int selectedPosition = spinnercolor.getSelectedItemPosition();
                spinSave(selectedPosition);
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
    }
    public void spinSave(int numberPosition) {
        colorPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = colorPref.edit();
        ed.putInt(COLOR_PREF, numberPosition);
    }
    public void spinLoad() {
        colorPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        int savedPosition = colorPref.getInt(COLOR_PREF, 0);
        spinnercolor.setSelection(savedPosition);
    }
}
```

Это нынешний код, при заходе в настройки с таким кодом вылетает. Почему?

Лог ошибок:

```
07-28 09:54:31.833 3456-3456/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10059: Read-only file system
07-28 09:56:38.379 3456-3456/com.churkin.oneapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.churkin.oneapp, PID: 3456
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.churkin.oneapp/com.churkin.oneapp.Settings}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
       Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
          at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:239)
          at com.churkin.oneapp.Settings.spinLoad(Settings.java:50)
          at com.churkin.oneapp.Settings.onCreate(Settings.java:28)
          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Если вылетает - приложите стектрейс

Comment: А где commit или apply при сохранении в preferences?

Comment: getSupportActionBar должен быть после setContentView

Comment: @LexHobbit apply поставил, getSupportActionBar(); прописал, все тоже самое (

Comment: @LexHobbit прикрепил лог ошибки к вопросу

Comment: @LexHobbit что-то не так в методе spinLoad как я понимаю

Comment: возможно под этой переменной в `SharedPreferences` у вас лежит `String`? Основная причина вылета, как я вижу, здесь: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:239)`. Попробуйте сменить значение `COLOR_PREF`

Comment: @Jarvis_J спасибо огромное) Поставил на COLOR_PREF значение 0 (в тексте), теперь спиннер сохраняет значение и загружает его даже после выхода из приложения :)

Comment: @АлександрЧуркин уменя ваш код полностью работет =) школьное расписание - это здорово =)

Comment: @LexHobbit у меня теперь тоже работает =)) C темами еще разберусь, а то скучно же смотреть на синий заголовок) Выбор должен быть какой-никакой

Comment: @АлександрЧуркин видимо вы изначально в эту константу (COLOR_PREF) сохранили `String`, а потом решили на int `поменять`

Comment: @Jarvis_J странно, сейчас ввел туда какую-то несуразицу как строку и все равно все работает... Значит в чем-то другом было дело...

Comment: @АлександрЧуркин `COLOR_PREF` - ключ в вашим сохраненным данным. В качестве него можно использовать любой допустимый набор символов. Видимо, изначально вы под этим ключом сохранили значение `String`. Сейчас конечно всё работает)